# Difference of Timestamp Rows in Pandas where Difference condition will be updated everytime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Sample `DataFrame` which has 2 Columns ID, Datetime.

```
ID          Datetime            
123         12Sep2021 10:00       
123         12Sep2021 10:10 
123         12Sep2021 10:25
123         12Sep2021 10:40
123         12Sep2021 10:52
123         12Sep2021 11:20
456         01Oct2021 09:00
456         01Oct2021 09:10
456         01Oct2021 09:40
```

I want to create a New Variable Count which will be updated based on Datetime difference as follows:

> For first transaction of an `ID`, `Count` will be 1. It will keep on
> incrementing till Difference is less than 30 minutes. If Difference is
> greater than 30 minutes, `Count` will again set to 1 and for next
> transactions of this `ID`, difference will be taken from `ID` which
> has `Count` 1.

The resultant Output will be as follows:

```
ID          Datetime              Count      
123         12Sep2021 10:00        1
123         12Sep2021 10:10        2
123         12Sep2021 10:25        3
123         12Sep2021 10:40        1
123         12Sep2021 10:52        2 
123         12Sep2021 11:20        1
456         01Oct2021 09:00        1
456         01Oct2021 09:10        2
456         01Oct2021 09:40        1
```

I have tried the following Pandas code :
`df1` is the Input `DataFrame`

```py
df2=df1['Datetime']df1.groupby('ID')['Datetime'].transform('first')
```

The problem is: how to reset the datetime value everytime when `difference > 30`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is this. I am not sure if there is a simple way of doing this.

```
d={i:j.Datetime.to_numpy() for i,j in  df.groupby("ID")}

di=dict()

for id in d.keys():
    n=1
    times=d[id]
    empty_list=list()
    first=times[0]
    for time in times:
        diff=time-first
        if diff >= np.timedelta64(30, 'm'):
            first=time
            n=1
        empty_list.append(n)
        di.update({id:empty_list})
        n+=1

df["Count"] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g:pd.Series(di[g.name])).to_list()
```

Comment: Thanks... It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please accept my answer clicking tick on the left ?